# Fixed nav works once then breaks

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, nav

I am creating a one page website with a fixed nav bar. When I load the page and click on a link it works and moves down to the correct link. However when I click on another link it scrolls back up to the header and after than any link will scroll to random parts of the page.

How do I create the nav so it scrolls to the specified link on the page?

I am using jquery to fix the header and smooth scroll.

HTML

```
    <div id="container">
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
            <nav class="fixed-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contMe">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </nav>
    </header>   
<div id="main">
        <section id="slider">
            <p>Slider here</p>
        </section>
        <section id="aboutMe">
        <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>about page here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="portfolio">
        <a id="portfolio" class="smooth"></a>
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        <p>portfolio page here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="Audio">
        <a id="Aud" class="smooth"></a>
        <h1>Munro Audio</h1>
        <p>Munro Audio page here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="contactMe">
        <a id="contMe" class="smooth"></a>
        <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        <p>Contact Me page here</p>
    </section>
</div>    
</div>
```

Smooth Scroll and fixed header Jquery

```
    <!-- smooth scroll -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
    //Fixed Header 

var headerHeight = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
    $('nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
  }
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
    body{
    position: relative;
    width:52.5%; /* 1000 px */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

#aboutMe, #portfolio, #munroAudio, #contactMe, #slider{
    top:60px;
    height:1000px;
    position:relative;  
}

#logo img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto !important;
}

header, header img, header nav{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; 

}

header{
    height:110px;
}


nav {
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #D24D57;
    color: #fff;
    height:60px;
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 52.5%;
  top: 0;
      z-index: 20;
}

.fixed-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fixed-nav ul li:hover {
  background: #E08283;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #E08283;
}
```

Comment: First thing I noticed is you have two elements with id `portfolio`, not sure if thats the problem though...

Comment: Thanks for the spot there. I changed the id but it still behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nt6g6p8/1/)

I removed the lines like `<a id="about" class="smooth"></a>` and pointed your nav links to the section IDs and it seems to work fine for me. I'm using `Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m` if it matters. I also added an offset for the slider which accounts for the header's height:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - $('header').height()
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
            <nav class="fixed-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contactMe">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </nav>
    </header>   
<div id="main">
        <section id="slider">
            <p>Slider here</p>
        </section>
        <section id="about">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>about page here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="portfolio">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        <p>portfolio page here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="audio">
        <h1>Munro Audio</h1>
        <p>Munro Audio page here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="contactMe">
        <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        <p>Contact Me page here</p>
    </section>
</div>    
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - $('header').height()
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
    //Fixed Header 

var headerHeight = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
    $('nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this right, but I think you want a sticky nav.

I have editted your css to the following:

```
.fixed-nav {
    height:60px;
    z-index:170;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Else there is this guide if you wan't to do it with more JQuery.

[JQuery Sticky Nav](http://designmodo.com/sticky-navigation-css-jquery/)

Comment: The sticky nav works but my issue is with the navigation, When I click on it the first time it goes to the appropriate section of the page, after that it just goes to any point on the page hear to the anchor.